# Why can't I use the REJECT policy on my iptables OUTPUT chain?

Tags: networking, iptables, gentoo

I currently have my OUTPUT chain set to DROP. I'd like to change it to REJECT, so that I have a clue that it's my firewall stopping me from getting somewhere rather than a problem with whatever service I'm attempting to access (immediate reject instead of timing out). However, iptables doesn't seem to care for this. If I manually edit my saved rules file and try to restore it, I get `iptables-restore v1.4.15: Can't set policy 'REJECT' on 'OUTPUT' line 22: Bad policy name` and it refuses to load the rules. If I attempt to set this manually (`iptables -P OUTPUT REJECT`), I get `iptables: Bad policy name. Run 'dmesg' for more information.` but there's no output in dmesg.

I've confirmed the appropriate rule is compiled into the kernel and I've rebooted to ensure it's loaded:

```
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TTL is not set
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
***
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REJECT=y
***
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ULOG=y
```

(Asterisks added to highlight applicable rule)

Everything I can find states that REJECT is a valid policy/target (in general), but I can't find anything that says it's not valid for the INPUT, FORWARD, or OUTPUT chains. My Google-fu isn't helping. I'm on Gentoo, if that makes any difference. Anyone here have any insight?

Comment: Can you show the `iptables` rule(s) in question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`REJECT` is a *target extension*, while a chain policy must be a *target*. The man page says that (although it's not really clear), but some of what it says is flat wrong.

The policy can only be `ACCEPT` or `DROP` on built-in chains. If you want the effect of rejecting all the packets that don't match the previous rules, just make sure the last rule matches everything and adds a rule with a `REJECT` target extension. In other words, after adding all relevant rules, do `iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -j REJECT`.

See the ["what are the possible chain policies" thread](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2003-March/043187.html) on the netfilter list for more details.

Comment: That makes sense, and a generic REJECT at the end should work. Out of curiosity, is the target *extension* definition somewhere fairly obvious and I just missed it, or is that one of the poorly documented bits?

Comment: Reading the whole man page, it's clear that REJECT is a target extension,  but the man page is **very** long so "TL;DR" tends to apply. It also implies that DROP, ACCEPT **and QUEUE** are valid policy targets; from the current code, QUEUE isn't!

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find it documented, but a reference [here](http://justlinux.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-50305.html) indicates that the only allowed policies are ACCEPTor DROP. This is confirmed by looking at the [source](https://git.netfilter.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=iptables.git;a=blob;f=libiptc/libiptc.c;h=f0f78155ad2d0776e3b66575683d7bcafaa68ad3;hb=HEAD) of `libiptc` (which is responsible for manipulating the rules) around line 2429, where the code has

```
2429         if (strcmp(policy, LABEL_ACCEPT) == 0)
2430                 c->verdict = -NF_ACCEPT - 1;
2431         else if (strcmp(policy, LABEL_DROP) == 0)
2432                 c->verdict = -NF_DROP - 1;
2433         else {
2434                 errno = EINVAL;
2435                 return 0;
2436         }
```

The original [thread](http://justlinux.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-50305.html) suggests the best thing to do is add REJECT at the end of the chain which should be `iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT`.

Note that the code just before this is:

```
2423         if (!iptcc_is_builtin(c)) {
2424                 DEBUGP("cannot set policy of userdefinedchain `%s'\n", chain);
2425                 errno = ENOENT;
2426                 return 0;
2427         }
2428
```

So you can't set the policy on a User Defined chain at all.

Comment: That command in the thread is incorrect; `-p` is for matching on a protocol; he meant `-A` like my answer says.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. The curiosity in me wonders if there's a reason behind it, or if that's just how things are, possibly for simplicity's sake (simpler code means fewer possible spots for vulnerabilities after all). If I were even a moderate developer I might be tempted to hack it in locally, but since I'm not, and given it's a piece of security, I'm not gonna touch it.

Answer (score 2):

`REJECT` on `OUTPUT` makes no sense; a `REJECT` will return an [ICMP packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) which would need to traverse a network.

Add a new `-j LOG` as your last rule (therefore before the `DROP` policy) to see what gets that far in the `OUTPUT` chain.

Comment: Couldn't the `REJECT` ICMP packet return on the lo interface? I agree that a `LOG` is useful for troubleshooting, but what I was really hoping for is a way to remind me that "Oh, yeah...that's probably being blocked by my `DROP` iptables default" instead of *troubleshoots for 5 minutes* *asks co-worker to access XYZ server* *realizes it's probably local*, which is my most common approach, since my typical workday rarely hits things I haven't opened a hole for already. Of course maybe I need to keep that in mind better, but a flat `REJECT` is more obvious.

Comment: I don't think you would want the `ethX` interface to generate traffic on the `lo` interface for many reasons. They are very independent; you can easily make chains apply to one and not the other.